# Specifying for ambiguous reference

Tags: c++, hash, ambiguous

In `mdart/mdart_function.h`, function `hash` is defined.

```
inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
    bitset<ADDR_SIZE> tempAddress_ (id);
    bitset<ADDR_SIZE> address_;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<ADDR_SIZE; i++) {
        if (tempAddress_.test(i)) {
            address_.set(ADDR_SIZE - 1 - i);
        }
    }
    address_.flip(ADDR_SIZE - 1);
    nsaddr_t temp = (nsaddr_t) address_.to_ulong();
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stdout, "\thash = %s\n", bitString(temp));
#endif
    return temp;
}
```

In another source file, the `hash` function is referenced with correct header include:

```
nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(reqId);
```

However, there is another `hash`, `std::hash` and it throws `error: reference to 'hash' is ambiguous` when I build it.

Is there any way to specify which `hash` the source code tries to use? I know `std::hash`, but how about `hash` in the header file?

Comment: In the header, there is `#define __mdart_function__` defined. Can I use it as a namespace? Anyway, I will try both `__mdart_function__::hash` and `::hash`. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use a macro definition as a namespace. But you can define your own namespace by putting `namespace myspace { .... }` around your function declaration(s) and definition(s). You can then refer to your function using `myspace::hash()`.

Comment: also - if you didn't have `using namespace std` - it wouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the namespace that the custom `hash` function is in to disambiguate it.  If it's not in an explicit namespace, then just `::hash()` will find it in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If your own hash implementation is in no particular namespace, you can use `::hash` to refer to it.